# pandas datareader should get stock market data but returns error

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, pandas-datareader

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_date = "2020-01-01"
end_date = "2020-12-31"

data = web.DataReader(name="TSLA", data_source='yahoo', start=start_date, end=end_date)
print(data)

close = data['Close']
ax = close.plot(title='Tesla')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Close')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

And this is the error that it returns:

```
File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 403, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    arg, _ = maybe_convert_dtype(arg, copy=False, tz=timezones.maybe_get_tz(tz))

TypeError: maybe_convert_dtype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tz'
```

It should display a graph of the stock.

Comment: I think `start=` and `end=` should be actual datetime objects, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
import locale
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()


start_date = "2020-01-01"
end_date = "2020-12-31"
ticker = 'TSLA'
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker,start=start_date, end=end_date)
print(data)

close = data['Close']
ax = close.plot(title='Tesla')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Close')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

to get
[image]

Comment: you are importing `from pandas_datareader import data as wb` as using it as pdr `data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker,start=start_date, end=end_date)`. This should be changed as `data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date)`. Also need to import library for `plt.show()`.